# Symfony controller unwanted output when I change the timezone

Tags: php, symfony

I need to change my Symfony server timezone but when I do it the response from this controller change
Here is the controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Entity\Licenses;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class UsersListController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/api/userslist", name="users_list")
     */
    public function getlist()
    {
                $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Licenses::class);
                $test = $repository->findAll();

                $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
                $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

                $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
                $abc = $serializer->serialize($test, "json");
                return new Response($abc);
    }
}
```

with postman when I request to this route the response is https://pastebin.com/manuyDcp but when I change the timezone to Europe/Paris inside php.ini file I got this kind of response https://pastebin.com/tQvhp1Yz . Sorry for the pastebin link.
Here is my Entity in case it can help

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Licenses
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="licenses", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_UNIQUE", columns={"id"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="license_key_UNIQUE", columns={"license_key"}), @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="user_uuid_UNIQUE", columns={"user_uuid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Licenses
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="license_key", type="string", length=100, nullable=false)
     */
    private $licenseKey;

    /**
     * @var string|null
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_uuid", type="string", length=30, nullable=true)
     */
    private $userUuid;

    /**
     * @var bool
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="is_set", type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $isSet = '0';

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false, options={"default"="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"})
     */
    private $date = 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP';

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getLicenseKey(): ?string
    {
        return $this->licenseKey;
    }

    public function setLicenseKey(string $licenseKey): self
    {
        $this->licenseKey = $licenseKey;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserUuid(): ?string
    {
        return $this->userUuid;
    }

    public function setUserUuid(?string $userUuid): self
    {
        $this->userUuid = $userUuid;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsSet(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->isSet;
    }

    public function setIsSet(bool $isSet): self
    {
        $this->isSet = $isSet;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->date;
    }

    public function setDate(\DateTimeInterface $date): self
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use AbstractNormalizer with the date format you want:

```
 // all callback parameters are optional (you can omit the ones you don't use)
    $dateCallback = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
        return $innerObject instanceof \DateTime ? $innerObject->format(\DateTime::ISO8601) : ''; // ISO is the format, you ca use 'Y-m-d :h:i:s' as well
    };

    $defaultContext = [
        AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
            'date' => $dateCallback, //date is the field $date
        ],
    ];

    $normalizer = new GetSetMethodNormalizer(null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);

    $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);

    $abc = $serializer->serialize($test, "json");
```

Comment: not sure to understand but it perfectly thanks a lot